# How to resend those emails which fails to dispatch from Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel server mail sometimes fails to deliver to recipients and I want to resend those emails until they send successfully to them, I want to manage it globally for whole app without using database help.

P.S. I'm using Laravel default Mail helper function in Laravel 6.2

I've tried with using try catch everywhere Mail helper function has been used, but this is something long and weird from code perspective.

Comment: What exception you are getting?

Comment: A mailserver already has the capability to resend emails that could not be delivered, but this depends on the kind of delivery problem. You really need to know exactly why the email wasn't delivered, to know if resending it is needed, and useful.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I'm using our organisation's custom mailserver and due to some lack of system configuration and high traffic on server I'm getting **Connection to ssl://upl*mail.*.in:465 Timed Out** error not every time, but sometimes frequently (3 out of 10)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The simple approach is just to increase the tries, if the job fail it will automatically run again until its completed or exhausted it tries.

By the queue command.

```
php artisan queue:work --tries=3
```

Or by a property on the job, if needed across multiple jobs, an abstract class would make it fairly easy to use in multiple jobs.

```
class YourJob
{
    public $tries = 5;
}
```

Since i assumed you already knew about retries, a way to have a little more extensive logic. Would be the option to dispatch the job again after failing, be careful as this could if not handle correctly keep spawning jobs if the error persists. Hook into the failed method of your job to create the logic, this will trigger if the job has failed. To avoid respawning all jobs, some assertion of which exceptions you want to run again.

```
class YourJob
{
    public function failed(Throwable $exception): void
    {
        if ($exception instanceof EmailSendFailed) {
            dispatch(new YourJob($this->someProperty));
        }
    }
}
```

The failed method solution would not be considered best approach, but more an approach to create some more advanced cases.